# How to select amongst multiple elements having same css?

Tags: css, selenium, xpath

I have multiple web elements on my page which have span tag and class name as '`nav-label`'. I am using Selenium webdriver to automate my application and I need to inspect the 3rd such element using cssSelector locator. I can easily do it by creating an XPath. I want to know if a CSS equivalent selector is possible or not.

Webelement:

```
<span class="nav-label">sometext</span>
```

When I write CSS as `css=.nav-label`, the inspector shows that there are 3 such elements. Now I want to select the third one. How can I do it using Css?

I can easily do it using xpath by writing xpath as `(//span[@class='nav-label'])[3]`

Is there a CSS equivalent of the above XPath?

Comment: You can use `:nth-child(3)`  to select the third element https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: nth-child would give me the 3rd child under a parent. In my case all these span tags are not under the same parent.

Comment: So you just want only the third element nav-label from all the present nav-label on your page? Can you please clarify this, I thought you wanted to select all the third elements nav-label inside or not of a parent. like this https://codepen.io/dobladov/pen/xmmRRb

Comment: Yes i want only the third element nav-label from all the present nav-label on my page. Like i said, this xpath (//span[@class='nav-label'])[3] gives me my desired result, but i want a css equivalent of the same.

Comment: If you want to get the third element in DOM having the class `.nav-label`, regardless of markup structure, there is no such selector. It's not possible with CSS alone. With JavaScript, you can use `document.getElementsByClassName("nav-label");` and fetch the third element.

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you want to achieve is not possible with CSS selectors.

[`:nth-of-type()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) would get you the closest, but only evaluates amongst siblings and will not find the nth item across levels.

You could use a CSS selector to identify all of the elements with that class, and then filter select the 3rd node, but that would not be as efficient and would require more code to maintain.

If you can use the XPath `(//span[@class='nav-label'])[3]` and it is working for you, then stick with that XPath expression.

Comment: OP seems looking for the Css alternative of `(//span[@class='nav-label'])[3]` and without the parent `:nth-of-type()`won't be effective.

Comment: My point is that nth-of-type() won’t work and there is no pure CSS expression that will select the desired element

Comment: Going with xpath since the css alternative of problem does not exist.